Is this problem linear?
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
&\max\min\{3x+4y,3x\}&\\
s.t. & \frac{x+y}{3x-1}\le8&\\
&x,y\le0&
\end{array}$$
I seem to have difficulty understanding this problem, which I guess is some kind of multi-objective linear programming model. I'm pretty sure this is not linear but I'm having trouble expressing the reasoning behind it. Another thing that I was wondering is "Can we convert this problem into a linear programming model?" If so, what is the easiest way to do it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Not linear, but linearizable.  Introduce variable $z$ to represent the $\min$ in the objective, and multiply both sides of the ratio constraint by $3x-1\le 0$.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
z &\le 3x+4y \\
z &\le 3x \\
x+y &\ge 8(3x-1) \\
x &\le 0 \\
y &\le 0
\end{align}
Because $y\le 0$, you know that $3x+4y \le 3x$, so $\min(3x+4y,3x)=3x+4y$, which leads to the simpler formulation to maximize $3x+4y$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
x+y &\ge 8(3x-1) \\
x &\le 0 \\
y &\le 0
\end{align}
